# When/why use an MVar over a TVar

Tags: haskell, shared-memory, stm

I find TVar's quite easy to work with even though MVar's appear a little simpler, while TVar's a little more featureful.

So my question is pretty simple, what condition do I want to go to MVar rather than TVar? I suppose anytime I don't need transactional update I **can** use an MVar, but in what way does that benefit me?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

TVars are safer but slower.

MVars can deadlock, but are much, much more efficient.

More efficient still is `IORef` and `atomicModifyIORef` (CAS), but that's highly restricted in what you can do with it.

It's really a safety over performance trade off. TVars are fully general, very safe. Everything else is less so, on a decreasing scale.

Comment: Efficiency, good 'nuff. I figured they were similarly performant, so moral of the story: Use a TVar if you need transactional update, otherwise use an MVar **because it will slow down your multi-threaded app considerably less**

Comment: Can anybody quantify the actual speed difference? (Presumably this is tricky to measure since it depends on actual thread interactions...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid ignoring concurrency issues: reading and writing an `IORef` will be your fastest operations, but GHC 7.8 shipped with some improvements to `MVar` that bring a `takeMVar/putMVar` within a few ns of a `read/writeIORef` (say 9.7/4.6 vs 3.7/7/3 on my machine (<usual disclaimer about lies and benchmarks here>)) and we also have a new very fast `readMVar` (when the MVar is full of course).

Comment: Also `atomicModifyIORef` performs very poorly under contention, for some reason.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I tried to benchmark `TVars` vs `modifyIORef` once. I made some bank account thing where threads would each do transactions between two bank accounts. The `IORef` implementation would end up with inconsistencies obviously. My first attempt managed to bench a random number generator, and my second attempt benched a faster random generator. I got a speed difference (~ twice as fast) on my third attempt where my random generator really wasn't random at all but just taking pregenerated numbers from an array. At that point I realised I didn't know what I was doing so I gave up.

Answer (score 47):

**MVar**

- can be empty
- used to implement synchronization patterns between threads
- allows one-way communication between threads
- can be faster than `TVar` in some cases

**TVar**

- can **not** be empty
- atomic transactions
- "shared memory" between threads; can be used to implement, for example, a lookup cache from which multiple threads can read/write
- access is linear time in the number of operations in the transaction log
- long running transactions are vulnerable to starvation if there are many shorter transactions, preventing them from commiting successfully

**IORef**

- mutable pointer-like reference
- often used for destructive `IO` writes/updates
- has atomic CAS operations, but complex transactional logic is better suited to a `TVar`

There is not really a hard and fast rule for when to use `MVar` or `TVar`.
If the resource I'm guarding will ever be "missing" (as opposed to empty, consider `Nothing` vs `Just mempty`), then `MVar` often makes the most sense. If I will need to perform atomic blocks of modifications to the resource, then `TVar` is most suitable.

Comment: You refer to shared MVar's for thread communication, shouldn't they only be used for one-way communication each though because if both threads are updating the same MVar to talk back and forth they're going to have race conditions?

Comment: you're correct. I didn't mean both threads would update the same `MVar`, I'll make that more clear

Comment: Might want to add a note about starvation too. MVars are guaranteed to be fair, TVars aren't.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa you can have several patterns with `MVar`, e.g: some threads putting others taking (essentially a 1-ary FIFO queue); many threads doing `modifyMVar` to modify some shared state; threads take a `()` before entering a critical section and replace when exiting (using it as a lock), etc.